# How to fetch images using a URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I have a UIView and I tried to fetch some data from an URL like following,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"www.url";
    // Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                           timeoutInterval:30.0];
        [request setValue:@"03f0d561-e173-4296-ab07-0ba301ca56bb" forHTTPHeaderField:@"token"];

        // Get the data
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        // Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
        if (data != nil) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];


                jsonDataDictionary = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];

            });
        }
    });
```

And when I'm running this code, images are black. Images didn't load. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does your URL include the scheme (e.g. "http://")? That's necessary. Log the `NSURL` and make sure it's not `nil`. Also, you say it's not working, but you're not using any of the `NSError` parameters to `NSURLConnection` or `NSJSONSerialization` which would tell you why it failed. You should be using those `NSError` parameters, logging them if it failed. Otherwise, you're flying blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code you posted.  For one, you should be using

```
  + (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                            queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response,
                                    NSData *data,
                NSError *connectionError))handler
```

instead of using a synchronous request off the main thread.  Anywho, the problem stems from how you're processing the data.  You're trying to parse it using NSJSONSerialization.  It's not JSON.  It's image data (presumably in .png or .jpg).

You need to use

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data
```

If this still doesn't work, copy paste the URL into your browser and see what MIME type it is

Answer (score 0):

I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), more easier than `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can fetch the images using url.If you do the following code easily fetch that.

Here the very very important things is when fetching the image from server

```
  -> First you have to convert to NSData

  -> After that you have to convert to image.
```

Below the coding part

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://www.url"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSError *err;

    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER in Google.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.

    //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

    //Now if you have IMAGE URL in Dictionary

    //Also you can use valueForKey instead of objectForKey for getting images from server

    NSString *stringImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Data"]objectForKey:@"ImageURL"];

                   OR
     //Now if you have image URL in Array of Dictionary

    NSMutableArray *array = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Data"];

    for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {

        NSString *stringImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]];

    }

    // Now Convert into Data from String

     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:stringImage]];

    // Now convert into Image from Data

    yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```